# Problem with using two navigation controllers in one application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am using one navigation controller in my application and using that I pushed my view to "another view controller". In that ("another view controller") I took another navigation controller with a tab bar controller and i started pushing views with the help of 2nd navigation controller(Here i made 1st navigation controller "HIDE"). So, now I want to go to 1st view of 1st navigation controller for that I created a home button and said "PoptorootviewController" but it is not working. Is there any way to go to 1st view of 1st navigation controller.

Need urgent help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [iPhone Tweetie Style Navigation Framework](http://www.wiredbob.com/2009/04/iphone-tweetie-style-navigation.html).